Crystal Report's printToPrinter is only printing to default server printer
I have been trying for weeks now to make this work. I have tried everything that I found online but I know that the right solution is out there somewhere.
I'm trying to print a Crystal Report (I'm using SAP Crystal Report 13) and .net 7 in my web app. I have tried everything but the code still only prints to the default system printer. Here is my code:
private void PrintFinalReport()
    {
      string printerName = @"\\ip@\printer_name";
      MyCrystalReport rpt = new MyCrystalReport ();
    
      string PdfPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "CReport.pdf");
      var lastObject = GetLastObjectForReport(PdfPath);
      var myobjects= new List<Object> { lastObject };
      DataTable myobjectsTable = ConvertToDataTable(myobjects);
      ///// rapport
      rpt.SetDataSource(myobjectsTable);
      rpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, PdfPath);
      rpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printerName;
      rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
    }

Now this works fine, but only on server default.
I have heard though that there is an issue with the method printToPrinter with crystal report version 13 and so I tried this :
rpt.ReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(printReportOptions);

But this doesn't print anything.
